# How to store json object in a column of mysql using spring boot/java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Requirement is like that a json object is send from postman and i need to receive it on a restcontroller
and save that whole json object as it is to the mysql database Table **Column**(in one/single column) using spring boot.

```
{
    "name" : "abc",
    "address : "xyz"
}
```

assume the above json object is send from postman to a spring boot  restcontroller. How can i save that
json object in a column of a table .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL supports JSON column types.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

So, assuming you will be using json column type for your requirement, you can follow below articles.
I was able to do this for postgres as well, works very well for me, the instructions are pretty straightforward.

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/
https://vladmihalcea.com/java-map-json-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: Helpful .. Thanks .

Comment: You need an external dependency for this approach

Answer (score 1):

There's no way. You can save it parsing the JSON to String ( Ex: `JSON.stringify()` ) and when you query the info , parse the string to JSON (Ex: `JSON.parse()` )

JSON.stringify:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify

JSON.parse: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse